# Double integral over a parallelogram (Fubini's theorem application)

Tags: integration

Using Fubini's theorem in $\Bbb R^2$ and, I guess, expriming $x$ and $y$ like this : $x \in [f(y), g(y)], y \in [a, b] : b \gt a, g(y) \gt f(y) \ \forall y \in [a, b], \ g, f$ continuous, I have to compute the double integral of $f(x, y) = y$ over the parallelogram $P$ delimited by the points $A = (0, 2), B = (1, 1), C = (3, 2), D = (2, 3)$.

I tried writing $P$ like this :

$P = \{ \vec{OA} + \alpha \vec{AD} + \beta \vec{AB}, \alpha , \beta \in [0, 1] \}$ $= \{ (0, 2) + \alpha (2, 1) + \beta (1, -1), \alpha , \beta \in [0, 1] \}$ $= \{ (x, y) : x = 2 \alpha + \beta, y = 2 + \alpha - \beta, \alpha , \beta \in [0, 1] \}$ $= \{ (x, y) : x + y = 2 + 3 \alpha, y = 2 + \alpha - \beta, \alpha , \beta \in [0, 1] \} = \ .. $

But I didn't manage to get something that would satisfy Fubini's hypothesis.
Someone told me to cut the parallelogram in two parts and compute the double integral over two triangles but I don't know why I can't get to the answer with what I was trying to do (or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf u = (1,-1), \mathbf v = (2,1)\\
(x,y) = (0,2) + \beta\mathbf u + \alpha\mathbf v\\
f(x,y) = y = 2 + \alpha - \beta\\ 
dx dy = ||\mathbf u \times \mathbf v||d\alpha\,d\beta = d\alpha\, d\beta\\
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 2 + \alpha - \beta \,d\alpha \,d\beta=2$